# Can't clone a remote repo when ufw is enabled

Tags: firewall, ufw, alpine-linux

I have a cloud VM running alpine3.15 [disk mode enabled] and I am able to clone/push/pull to github when ufw is off. However when it is on, all git commands that talk to github get stuck (no output)

I have tried testing through ssh but that gets stuck too:

```
ssh -vvvT git@github.com

OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.113.4] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
```

Below is the status of ufw:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
SSH                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
SSH (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

DNS                        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
DNS (v6)                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

Currently, I temporarily turn ufw off and on when I want to clone/push (no risk as there nothing important in the VM), but it is a pain to have to do that everytime.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The status looks like from `ufw status`. Please post the output of `ufw status verbose` instead. Does it print `deny (outgoing)`?

Comment: You are right! I had it deny outgoing requests by default. Removing the rule fixed it. If you want to put an answer I can accept it.Thank you for your help.

Comment: No time at the moment for a good, educative answer. If anyone (e.g. you) posts the solution then I won't mind at all. Please do.